Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, Exercise 1.3.W - Pullback square exists if map is monic
In this exercise, the goal is to show that a morphism $\pi: X \to Y$ is a monomorphism iff the fibered product $X \times_Y X$ exists and that the induced diagonal morphism $\delta_\pi: X \to X \times_Y X$ is an isomorphism.
I have shown that a monomorphism gives the fibered product, but I'm struggling with the other direction. Since this question comes before the Yoneda lemma in the text, I would like to see a proof avoiding the lemma. From the diagram 
we see that the diagonal map $\delta_\pi$ admits two left inverses $p, q$. How do we see that these are right inverses, and thus deduce that they are equal? Once $p = q$ it follows that $\pi$ is a monomorphism, so this is all I'm missing.
(The same question is asked here, but I don't think knowing that $\pi p = \pi q$ is enough to conclude that $p = q$ unless we already knew that $\pi$ is a monomorphism.)

How are you concluding that $\pi$ is a monomorphism from $p = q$? Could you apply the same argument to the pullback square $\mathrm{id}_X, \mathrm{id}_X, \pi, \pi$ induced by the isomorphism, with $\mathrm{id}_X = \mathrm{id}_X$?

Your claim $p = q$ is not true! These are the two projection functors onto the factors of the fiber product.

It is true. Writing $i$ for the inverse to $\delta_\pi$, you have $p = \mathrm{id}_X \circ i = q$.

@NaïmFavier why is the square you've mentioned a pullback square? If $g$, $h$ are distinct morphisms satisfying $\pi g = \pi h$, both $g$ and $h$ are maps to $X$ commuting with the identities. So I don't think the universal property is satisfied.

The property of being a pullback is preserved by isomorphisms of cones, like $\delta_\pi$. This isn't difficult to show.

Apologies for the wait on a reply, I was a little intimidated by the statement on isomorphisms of cones. I think my question still stands... we certainly want to have an inverse $i$ for $\delta_\pi$ and we would get one if $(X, \text{id}_X, \text{id}_X)$ was a pullback, but all we have is the existence of a pullback and a diagonal map to that pullback from $X$ which has left inverses.

This question has cleared this up for me by providing a counterexample. I had misinterpreted the question in Vakil and was trying to prove that a pullback square for the diagram 
implies that $\pi$ is a monomorphism, but one needs the additional assumption that the map $\delta_\pi$ is an isomorphism.
